# C# generics class operators not working

Tags: c#, generics, operators

I have a problem with generic. When I try to use less operators in generic, their call is not happening. But it works with the method Equals.
That is a some test class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int i;

    static public Boolean operator ==(Test obj1, Test obj2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("operator ==");
        return obj1.i == obj2.i;
    }

    static public Boolean operator !=(Test obj1, Test obj2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("operator !=");
        return obj1.i != obj2.i;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("operator equals");
        return this == (Test)obj;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HashCode");
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And class Checker:

```
public class Checker
{
    public Boolean TestGeneric<T>(T Left, T Right) where T : class
    {
        return Left == Right; //not work override operators
        return Left.Equals(Right); //work fine
    }
}
```

Small testing:

```
Test left = new Test() { i = 4 };
Test right = new Test() { i = 4 };
var checker = new Checker();
Console.WriteLine(checker.TestGeneric<Test>(left, right));
Console.ReadKey();
```

How I can use less operators in class Test from generic?

Comment: please don't override equals unless you know what you are doing. Even then, think twice!

Comment: `return 5;` is not the greatest hash code.

Comment: Yes. You should use 666 instead.

Comment: @Jodrell Why? There are no collisions in any possible set of 1 items.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Rotem, well, if `i` was private ... that implementation is also good for sets of 0 items.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, 42 is the only obviously correct value ;)

Comment: "Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is not recommended."

Comment: @Jodrell Even more powerful than first imagined! ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Overloaded operators are static methods, so they don't participate in polymorphism; they are resolved statically at compile time, based on the known type of the operands.

In a generic method, the compiler can't know that `T` will be `Test` (since it could actually be anything else), so it uses the most general definition of `==`, which is reference comparison.

Note that if you add a constraint on the generic method to force `T` to be `Test` or a subclass of `Test`, it will work as expected, but of course it won't work anymore for other types...

Answer (score 0):

This now works in C# 11 / .NET 7 (or above):

```
public class Test : IEqualityOperators<Test, Test, bool>
{ /* no changes except ^^^ addition */ }

public bool TestGeneric<T>(T Left, T Right) where T : IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool>
{
    return Left == Right; // does what you expect
}
```