# A value is null, but the check returns otherwise?

Tags: c#, debugging, null, unity-game-engine

EDIT: [This explains everything!](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) - Unity creates managed fake wrappers around your UnityEngine.Objects when you destroy them. That means if you destroy a UEObject, the C# wrapper could still be not null. The == is implemented in a custom way so that when you destroy a UEObject checking == null will return true. This obviously doesn't play well with generics.

---

This is literally driving me insane. I have this method right here:

```
public static void AssertNotNullAfterAssignment<T>(ref T value, Func<T> get, string msg) where T : class
{
    if (value == null)
        value = get();
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException(msg);
}
```

I'm calling it on a reference that is null at the start:

```
AssertNotNullAfterAssignment(ref fovMeshFilter, GetComponent<MeshFilter>, "fovMeshFilter");
```

What's really insane, is that the check `if (value == null)` is returning false! even though the value IS null!

[Here's a short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpB-X6TE_88&feature=youtu.be) I made showing this.

What's interesting though, if I copy/paste the method code to the method I used it in (in OnEnable) it works (pretty much what I have commented in OnEnable in the video)

So... it works if it was outside the assertion method, but not inside. I also tried `Equals` instead of `==` but the same.

Anybody has any idea what's going on?

Edit: Here's OnEnable, the method I'm calling the assertion from:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    //if (fovMeshFilter== null)
    //  fovMeshFilter= GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    //if (fovMeshFilter== null)
    //  throw new NullReferenceException("fovMeshFilter");

    AssertNotNullAfterAssignment(ref fovMeshFilter, GetComponent<MeshFilter>, "fovMeshFilter");
}
```

If I use the uncommented lines it works as expected, but the assertion method doesn't work for some only-god-knows-why reason.

Edit1: What we have here?

[image]

Edit2:

[image]

Edit3:

So after the great help from this awesome community, and couple of tests I came to the solution. *I could have sworn it was one of the very first things I tried! you must believe me! XD* - It was just to use `.Equals` instead of `==` - Like @Edin shows in his answer, doing a `==` on a generic object seem to call `System.Object`'s `==` - But, calling `.Equals` should always resolve to the correct overload of `Equals`. I don't know why is it this way, I mean, why don't the '==' also resolve to the correct overload?

Comment: sorry, spoke too soon. it appears like === is not a valid c# operator.

Comment: @Tim Sorry it's in the video. It's the method that I was using `AssertNotNullAfterAssignment` from. I'll add it to the question as well.

Comment: I've seen this when there was a badly-implemented `==` operator, but in the code you show, this *should* be using the `object ==`, since nothing more is known. But still, could you try: `if((object)value == (object)null)` ?

Comment: However, I've googled this, and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx, object == object checks if they refer to the same object (i.e. memory location). does that object have an equals operator? try that if so.

Comment: From your video, it seems the value is not null. If you look closer, you see an arrow next to it on the left side. That means that is an object. What do you see when you expand it?

Comment: vexe, in your video, when you mouse over `value` you see it is `null`, but you also see a little triangle to the left of it, as if you can expand it. Did you try expanding it? Because you don't get that triangle when mouse overing the `null` itself. Maybe its not null, but its an object, with a .toString() returning `null`.

Comment: It's not a struct is it?

Comment: @nl-X you are right. Added an image. See edit.

Comment: Your image answers your question. It is obviously not null.

Comment: @MarcGravell: casting to `object` didn't change anything. @Nate: I tried Equals too, same.

Comment: @vexe the exception you see in the screenshot is caused during debugging/mouse overing I think. Inore the exception, if it does not popup during normal work. But do expand the little triangles everywhere.

Comment: @Stefan "where T : class" - could you elaborate more?

Comment: @Edin: so it's not null, but ... null? How do you describe this object?

Comment: @nl-x: I tried it without `ref`. Same.

Comment: @vexe: See nl-x's answer. The "null" you're reading is the result of the object's `.ToString()`. Try passing in an actual null manually and you should see the correct behaviour

Comment: @vexe: that is a DebuggerDisplay string for that object. You can set your object display anything you want in the debugger. I guess for this object, it is written "null" in case some backing property is null or its `ToString()` returns `"null"`. In any case your object is not null and that is why your check returns false.

Comment: @BenAaronson how did the `.ToString()` get passed?

Comment: @vexe That's just what the debugger displays there. Though perhaps Edin's comment above is more accurate

Comment: Alright I changed the argument to be a normal `T value` (no ref) and passed a `(MeshFilter)null` - I got the expected behaviour like you said @BenAaronson

Comment: What I'm failing to understand, why does it work correctly in OnEnable, but passing to a method does not?

Comment: @vexe What does working correctly in OnEnable mean? You uncomment all those commented lines and it throws a NullReferenceException, or something else?

Comment: @everyone: I'm very thankful to your help guys. Really appreciate it! Please see my last edit. I understand that you're saying. But the object 'is' null. Performing the check in OnEnable returns true. Doing the same thing in the assertion method yeilds all those strange results.

Comment: @vexe That's still not a null object. I notice it's a different type though. The only guess I can make is that `MeshRenderer` has overrided its `.Equals()` to compare as equal to a `null` object if its underlying object is `null`, whereas `MeshFilter` hasn't.

Comment: Try doing the same as you're doing in the second screenshot, but with a `MeshFilter` rather than a `MeshRenderer`. That should test if my guess is right

Comment: @BenAaronson both `MeshRenderer` and `MeshFilter` behaved the same.

Comment: I'm starting to think Unity has something to do with this. Each `UnityEngine.Object` has an internal unmanaged representation at its C++ side. We (users) only deal with the managed side. So for ex if I set a UnityEngine object to null, my understanding is that it's not wiped out actually but now leaked. To destroy an Unity object I have to call Destroy on it (a Unity method). I'm not sure, but maybe both the meaning of nulls to C# and C++ are conflicting here? - I have never came across this before...

Comment: @vexe Okay, so just to check that you're testing everything right, do: `private void OnEnable(){bool b1 = fovMeshFilter == null; AssertNotNullAfterAssignment(ref fovMeshFilter, GetComponent<MeshFilter>, "fovMeshFilter"); }`, with no other lines in between. And on the first line of the `AssertNotNull...` method, do: `bool b2 = value == null`. Put a break point on the next line after that, and check the values of `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: @BenAaronson `b1` was true, `b2` was false.

Comment: Added another test: `void Test(MeshFilter mf) { bool b3 = mf == null; }` - b3 was true as well. So pretty much it's cause of generics. No idea why though. I mean, how is the `==` differ in these two contexts?

Comment: I'm stumped, I'm afraid. But at least you probably know how to proceed: don't compare to null, work out what property on the Unity classes needs to not be null and compare with that instead.

Comment: @vexe Have you tried what i suggested in my answer? did you do something like `var foo = value.mesh` inside the function, and set your debugger and watch to see foo ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Got an exception. Commented on your answer.

Comment: @everyone thanks a lot! problem solved using `Equals` (see edit) @NateKerkhofs suggested to use it in one of the very first comments. However believe me I did! and it didn't work at that time idk. You have no idea! When working with Unity you could see things that other people wouldn't just believe from you so easily... like your son seeing a killer doll. Exactly the same. Apologies for the confusion everyone.

Comment: I just wanted to offer my condolences and to announce that this has inspired me to program only in assembler with no libraries henceforth, for safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object is not null. Seeing `null` in debugger does not mean it is a null reference. If you can expand object in the debugger, it is most certainly not null reference. It might be that the `DebuggerDisplay` string or `ToString()` method return `"null"` in your case but that is not the same as null reference.

Take an example of this class

```
[DebuggerDisplay("null")]
class A { }
```

An instance `a` of `A`

```
var a = new A();
```

will be displayed as `a|null` in the debugger when you run over it with your mouse.

Your `T` most certainly has this attribute. `ToString()` override which returns `"null"` would add additional curly braces around the string: `a|{null}`.

**EDIT:**

Seeing your Edit2, made me realize what your real problem might be. Your `==` operator is most probably overriden, so that it returns true in some cases when you compare an instance of your class to null, although an instance itself is not null. However, in generic method it is not known what type your parameter is at compile time, therefore the most general operator will be applied on your `T` parameters, which is reference comparison. This is well described in the following thread: [C# generics class operators not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181921/c-sharp-generics-class-operators-not-working)

That could be the reason why the comparioson in `OnEnable()` works, and the comparison inside your generic method does not.

However this is not completely proven, since I cannot see your code. But you could verify that.

And here is a full working example of the operators not working properly in combination with generics:

```
class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }            

  public static bool operator ==(Person left, Person right)
  {
    // we consider Person null when it either has no Name or it is a null reference.
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, left) || left.Name == null)
      return object.ReferenceEquals(null, right);
    return left.Equals(right);
  }

  public static bool operator !=(Person left, Person right) { return !(left == right); }
  // Note that == and != operators should ideally be implemented in combination of Equals() override.
  // This is only for making an example for this question
}

private static bool IsNull<T>(T val)
{
  return val == null;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Person person = new Person();
  //this will display: person == null => True
  Console.WriteLine("person == null => {0}", person == null);
  //this will display: IsNull<Person>(person)=> False
  Console.WriteLine("IsNull<Person>(person)=> {0}", IsNull(person));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you're saying. The debugger could say it's null but it's not. However, I'm sure that it 'is' null. Performing the check in OnEnable returns true. Please see last edit.

Comment: I can confirm that both `MeshRenderer` and `MeshFilter` don't have this debugger attribute on them. Following up the hierarchy of objects, I ended up in `UnityEngine.Object` with its `ToString` implementation not visible to the decompiler so I cannot say anything about how `MeshFilter`/`MeshRednerer` `ToString` is implemented.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your edit. I think this what makes the most sense at this moment. Idk though, I have dlls with tons of generic static/utils/helpers that deal with Unity stuff at will. This is the first time I come across this.

Comment: In your example however, the result could be 'false' for both the logs if `Equals` was used instead. In this case, `System.Object`'s `Equal` is used cause it's not overloaded in `Person`. We can overload it and have it return `person1 == person2` So now both the logs print true. But not in any case will one of the logs print different results when using `Equals` - Not in my case, I tried using `Equals` - same problem (different results in OnEnable and the assertion method)

Comment: @vexe: I do not see your point. Equals is not overriden in my example, therefore calling it, will do a whole different comparison than `==` currently does. See my comment on `Equals()` inside the code. When you override equality operators, ideally you would override `Equals()` with your `equals logic` and call it inside the operators `==` and `!=`. That way, operators and equals would behave the same. I did not do it for sake of simplicity.

Comment: Oops... looks like I figured it out. Thanks to you I wouldn't have given Equals another try. I could have sworn it was one of the first many things I tried, idk maybe I got lost.

What I was trying to say was (at least from the first impression I took) is that if you try `fovMeshRenderer.Equals(null)` in OnEnable, it works (returns true) - however if you try it inside the generic it returns false. I was saying that it should return true since it should resolve to the actual Equals of the object whose type is `T` and not System.Object's Equals.

Comment: let me make sure a 100% first lol don't wanna speak too soon. Unity could change its mind. Depending on the quality of its internal espresso machine.

Comment: OK I can confirm it's working (at least for now) - I will add what happened as a detail to my question instead of posting an answer. However, I wonder why does calling Equals from a generic method on a generic object resolve to the correct version of Equals, but not when doing a `==`...

Comment: @vexe: Equals is an instance method which is overriden, whereas operator is static (method). What operator to call is decided at compile-time. Since compiler has no idea what your T will be, it uses standard reference comparison operator. What overload of Equals to call is however determined through an instance on which you call it. Knowing that `Equals()` works, means it is well implemented, and your troubles resulted from operators and generics usage incompatibility.

Comment: This is what I call.... hard.... earned.... knowledge! :) At least I know I'm not totally insane now lol... rational explanation always exist. Must have a firm belief on that.

Answer (score 3):

vexe, in your video, when you mouse over value you see it is null, but you also see a little triangle to the left of it, as if you can expand it. Did you try expanding it? Because you don't get that triangle when mouse overing the null itself. Maybe its not null, but its an object, with a `.toString()` returning null.

**edit**

I think your object is NOT null. And that your debugger is failing to show you the correct value. (Hence the exception in your screenshot.)
Try doing someting like `var foo = value.mesh;` inside your called function, and debug on that one instead.

It seems as though this object is not so breakpoint/watch friendly.

Comment: +1 for noticing the triangle which indicates that the debugger recognizes it as an object

Comment: I don't think the debugger is failing to do anything, I think the two properties that have exceptions are probably trying to access whatever the underlying null value is

Comment: Thanks for your answer @nl-x. I tried your foo thing, I got an exception: `UnassignedReferenceException: The variable fovMeshFilter of FOV2DEyes has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the fovMeshFilter variable of the FOV2DEyes script in the inspector.` - pretty much saying that the meshFilter is not assigned (value is null)

Comment: @vexe uhm. So you did `var foo = value.mesh;` inside `AssertNotNullAfterAssignment()` and the debugger then starts talking about `fovMeshFilter`? But there is no `fovMeshFilter` mentioned inside `AssertNotNullAfterAssignment()`.

Comment: Thank you nl-x. Problem solved. See last edit. And see the link in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
I was trying this:

```
 public bool IsDisabled()
{
    Debug.Log("in is disabled check and my image name is " + myImage.sprite.name  +"i return="+ (myImage.sprite == Disabled));
    return (myImage.sprite==Disabled);
       
}
```

The debug log would return false but the return value would be true. Then I used

```
return (myImage.sprite.Equals(Disabled));
```

and it worked fine. Really strange since I am not deleting any gameobjects.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31715167)